# Optimizaion of calculating how many data.frame record timestamps appear in a one second window from every record timestamp in that data.frame

Tags: r, optimization, dataframe, data.table, self-reference

I have an R data.frame with a number of columns, one of which contains POSIXct timestamp records.  I want to add a column to the data.frame that, for each row, contains the number of records that have a timestamp between that row's timestamp and one second into the future.

The following code implements this, but it's really slow on the data I'm processing (often 60K+ records).  I'd like to know if there is a way to speed this up.

```
# Create a data frame with POSIXct values spread over a few minutes.
# The actual number of records can be over 60,000.
set.seed(1234)
times <- as.POSIXct("2015-02-18 11:39:17.104206 AEDT") + 
    runif(n = 10000, min = -5*60, max = 5*60)
times <- sort(times) # my source data comes to me sorted
times <- data.frame(datetime = times)

# For each event (timestamp), calculate how many events (timestamps) appear in
# a one second window following that event.
system.time(
for (i in 1:length(times$datetime)) {
        times$eventCount[i] <- sum(
                times$datetime >= times$datetime[i] & 
                times$datetime < times$datetime[i] + 1)
}
)
```

The result on my system is:

```
user  system elapsed
8.10    0.00    8.21
```

Interestingly, the processing time does not scale linearly with the number of records.  For 20K records, the user time is 24.74 seconds.

Looking at similar questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14092162/most-efficient-vectorization-when-using-previous-calculated-value-rolling?lq=1) one and the referenced questions therein) would suggest that using a data.table should speed things up considerably, but I can't bridge the gap between the code in those answers (which look at a fixed number of records either side of a given record) to what I need (looking at an unknown number of records to one side of a given record).

rcpp looks like it would be the best way to go, but I don't know any c++ at all.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I wonder if a binary search, halving intervals until the largest item within the 1 second window would be better?

Comment: I've added the Rcpp implementation reflecting the @BondedDust's suggestion. It is plentiful fast.

Comment: Strong work @Khashaa. I'm unable to add any more upvotes since I upvoted your first effort. You have my respect.

Comment: Thank you, @BondedDust. I am flattered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simpler logic based on @Kashaa's Rcpp solution.

#### data

```
require(dplyr)
require(data.table)
set.seed(1234L)
dt = data.table(datetime=as.POSIXct("2015-02-18 11:39:17.104206 AEDT") + 
    runif(n = 100000, min = -5*60, max = 5*60), key="datetime")
df = as.data.frame(dt)
```

#### data.table solution

```
setNumericRounding(0L)
betweendt <- function(x, col, eps) {
    idx1 = dt[.(col), mult="first", roll=-Inf, which=TRUE]
    idx2 = dt[.(col+1-eps-unclass(col)*eps), 
                mult="last", roll=Inf, which=TRUE]
    idx2-idx1+1L
}
system.time({
dt[, eventC := betweendt(dt, dt$datetime, .Machine$double.eps)]
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.043   0.001   0.045
```

#### Rcpp version (from @Khashaa)

```
system.time({
  col = df$datetime
  df <- df %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(eventC = betweenCpp(col, datetime, datetime+1)) 
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.142   0.001   0.142 

identical(df$eventC, dt$eventC)
# [1] TRUE
```

`data.table` solution is ~3x faster here.

---

Refer to history for the older version using `foverlaps()` (which was an overkill).

Comment: @Arun, thank you very much indeed.  This absolutely kills it.  My 20k example runs with your code at `0.16` seconds down from over 27 seconds, and the original 10k example has gone from 7.6 seconds to `0.04` seconds.  A-freaking-mazing.  Is it unhealthy that I get a warm feeling inside when I think about data.table?  Thanks for your work and reply here.

Comment: @Khashaa - My first attempts with this code were also out by up to five counts, but when I `setNumericRounding(0)` the results were identical.

Comment: this looks good, but in trying to wrap your new code in a function for use in the rbenchmark::benchmark function I get a **`Error in betweendt(dt, dt$datetime, .Machine$double.eps) : 
  could not find function "." `** error.  Oddly, I don't get this error if I run the code directly in the console.  Is this where I should be using the dev version of data.table?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
dt <- times$datetime
system.time({
times <- times %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(eventCount = sum(between(dt, datetime, datetime+1))) 
})
```

On AWS free-tier,

```
user  system elapsed 
3.309   0.048   3.358
```

**[Edit]**

Apparently, `between` from `dplyr` is quite slow. Implementing this step in Rcpp is easy and turned out to be very fruitful. `betweenCpp(v,x,y)` behaves like `sum(between(v, x, y))`, i.e., counts the elements of 'v' lying between `x` and `y`.

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('int betweenCpp(NumericVector v, double x, double y) {
                  NumericVector::iterator low1, low2;
                  low1=std::lower_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), x);
                  low2=std::lower_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), y);
                  return (low2 - low1);
                  }')
```

Now, the power of Rcpp at our disposal, following took 0.28 sec on my mediocre laptop for `n=100.000`.

```
dt <- times$datetime
system.time({
  times <- times %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(eventC = betweenCpp(dt, datetime, datetime+1)) 
})
```

**[Addendum]**

If you want extra speed, you can do full Rcpp implementation.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace Rcpp;

int betweenCpp(NumericVector v, double x, double y) {
  NumericVector::iterator low1, low2;
  low1=std::lower_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), x);
  low2=std::lower_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), y);
  return (low2 - low1);
}
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector EventCountCpp(NumericVector x) {
  int n=x.size();
  NumericVector count(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    count[i]=betweenCpp(x, x[i], x[i]+1);
  }
  return(count);
}
```

Saving this as `count.cpp` in your working directory, then following took 0.01s for `n=100.000`.

```
sourceCpp("count.cpp")
system.time(times$EventCount <- EventCountCpp(times$datetime))
```

Comment: Looks pretty good. On my machine where my improved version ran in 6 seconds yours runs in 2.4 seconds.

Comment: Mate, that is excellent.  I get 2.08 seconds for the 10,000 row version.  That's a reduction of about 75%!  Thanks.  Do you think there is much more to be had by going to data.table?  I ask because some of the files I process are taking over 30 minutes with my code, and even with your dplyr code, that would be over five minutes.

Comment: For the 20K version I get 12.4 seconds. So still seems to scale quadratically, ... but from an improved baseline. For 40K, it's 90.3 versus 54.9

Comment: @vorpalwabbit I have no idea about data.table option. Have you considered parallelization?

Comment: @BondedDust I didnt try large values, but seems like the search really is costly.

Comment: @Khashaa: No, I've not considered it.  The machine that will run this script only has two cores, but that's interesting.  Perhaps the comments are not a great place to talk in detail about that option.  Could you point me towards something I should read (e.g. an R package)?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @vorpalwabbit I've added a simple parallelization example. Hope it helps.

Comment: dplyr's `between()` includes bounds. So you're checking for `<= datetime+1`.

Comment: @Arun, tnx for pointing out? Is there `data.table` possibility?

Comment: @Khashaa - OK, that has to be the fastest result without resorting to FPGAs or machine code.  Thanks!  I will have to learn some more about Rcpp (perhaps [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html)), because it seems formidable.  
I used [tag:rbenchmark]::benchmark to test the [tag:data.table] and [tag:Rcpp] solutions on 100k records.  Here's the result:  
`           test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
2 f_Rcpp(times)           20    5.57    1.000      5.57      0.0
1   f_DT(times)           20   18.22    3.271     16.41      1.8`

Comment: Sorry - my comment formatting skills are not great.  What I meant to show was that the 100k rows were processed 20 times over in 16.41 seconds by data.table, and in 5.57 seconds by Rcpp.  Amazing.

Comment: @vorpalwabbit Really should learn Rcpp. You can learn rudimentaries of it in a day or two. I have only limited command of Rcpp, but it really pays off. On the other note, `data.table` achieves something comparable to Rcpp in speed. Amazing stuff. Too bad that I find its syntax little too daunting.

Answer (score 1):

It more than doubles for me when hte number is increased. I though that maybe I could get better performance by avoiding all the use of "$" access to the dataframe which wasn't effective, but I do see a way to save some time. You shouldn't be testing for the number of times less than the current time since you know the answer to that (i-1) already given the sorted nature of the data. Just record the number of items ahead that are within 1 second. (My processor is about the same as yours, so this result is actually about 25 % faster than the first one:

```
system.time( {dt <- times$datetime
 for (i in 1:length(dt)) {
         eventCount[i] <- sum(
                 tail(dt, 10000-i) < dt[i] + 1)
 }}
 )
   user  system elapsed 
  5.410   0.716   6.042
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, results are different between your solution and OP's one.

Comment: How much different? I get a mean that is exactly different by 1.0 (17.66 and 16.66) .  I think the the values are shifted exactly one unit. since the lowest values are 0 in one case with max of 36 and 1 and 37 in the other case.

Comment: Thanks BondedDust.  With slightly amended code (need to add one to the count) I get 4.75 seconds for the 10,000 record example.